# Why aren't I catching this exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, exception

I'm a little puzzled by some error reports I'm getting from my Windows Phone 8 app as I was under the impression my try catch block you see in the code below should be catching this particular issue:

```
private async void ConnectionReceivedCallback(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    DataReader reader = new DataReader(args.Socket.InputStream);
    reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    uint numStrBytes = await reader.LoadAsync(512);
    string request = reader.ReadString(numStrBytes);

    using (IOutputStream output = args.Socket.OutputStream)
    {
        string requestMethod = request.Split('\n')[0];
        string[] requestParts = requestMethod.Split(' ');

        if (requestParts[0] == "GET")
        {
            string url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(requestParts[1].Replace("/?", ""));

            int z = Convert.ToInt32(GetUrlParam(url, "z"));
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(GetUrlParam(url, "x"));
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(GetUrlParam(url, "y"));

            y = GetYForTmsTileSystem(y, z);

            bool foundTileProvider = false;
            if (MapTileHelper.IsMapTileValid(x, y, z))
            {
                foreach (IMapTileProvider tileProvider in _tileProviders)
                {
                    if (tileProvider.CanProvideMapTile(x, y, z))
                    {
                        foundTileProvider = true;
                        try
                        {
                            await tileProvider.SendMapTileResponse(x, y, z, output);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            // Just fail nicely if there's an issue
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!foundTileProvider)
            {
                using (Stream resp = output.AsStreamForWrite())
                {
                    byte[] headerArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                        "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n" +
                        "Content-Length:0\r\n" +
                        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
                    await resp.WriteAsync(headerArray, 0, headerArray.Length);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException("HTTP method not supported: " + requestParts[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm seeing bug reports coming in like the following:

```
System.Exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at TopoMap.Map.MapTileServer.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__4(Object state)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

In case it's relevant, the code executed inside the try catch block:

```
public async Task SendMapTileResponse(int x, int y, int zoomLevel, IOutputStream response)
{
    string url = MapTileHelper.BuildMapTileUrl(x, y, zoomLevel);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) return;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        Stream imageStream = null;

        HttpResponseMessage mapTileResponse = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        if (mapTileResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            imageStream = await mapTileResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }

        if (imageStream != null)
        {
            using (Stream resp = response.AsStreamForWrite())
            {
                MapTileProviderHelper.WriteImageHeaderToResponseStream(resp, imageStream.Length);

                // Cache map tile
                if (UserData.CacheMap)
                {
                    // NOTE: BinaryWriter inside this method will close the imageStream once it's done, so we need to reload the image!
                    //       Also tried imageStream.CopyToAsync(resp) before saving image, but this doesn't work well either.
                    SaveImage(MapTileHelper.GetMapTileCacheFilePath(x, y, zoomLevel), imageStream);

                    using (IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(MapTileHelper.GetMapTileCacheFilePath(x, y, zoomLevel), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            await fs.CopyToAsync(resp);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await imageStream.CopyToAsync(resp);
                }

                await resp.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I might be seeing these exceptions?

Comment: you sure that the stack is comming from inside the try catch and not some other code in ConnectionReceivedCallback, like LoadAsync?

Comment: What call actually throws the exception? Have you gone through it with the debugger? You'll know an exception has been thrown when your call stack suddenly goes back to its calling methods.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - I've not been able to replicate this exception in development unfortunately. This is from a few bug reports received from out in the wild.

Comment: @Linky - I'm not 100% sure, but I guess you could be right. Had my blinkers on it seems! I'll try wrapping the LoadAsync code in a try catch block also and wait to see if the issue still gets reported. Thanks for the potential fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown in the thread that executes the async method and so the exception is not propagated to the main thread. You should handle the exception in the method and notify the main thread through information contained in the returned Task variable.

Comment: I catch an exception directly within the SendMapTileResponse, but if one is thrown by a child async function call then I do indeed fail to trap that exception. Thanks for you answer - much appreciated.